# How can a subset be disjointed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the proof: Suppose A,B, and C are sets. Prove that C⊆A∆B iff C⊆A∪B and A∩B∩C=∅.

If I suppose that C ⊆A∆B, how can the three sets be disjointed?

Comment: Did you try a few examples? It should follow simply by applying the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the direction that you seem to be having trouble with.

Let $x\in C$ and suppose that $C\subset A\triangle B$, then $$x\in A\triangle B=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)\subset A\cup B$$ and so $x\in A\cup B$. Now suppose that $x$ is in $(A\cap B)\cap C$, then $x\in A\cap B$. But this means that $x\notin (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ which contradicts $x\in C\subset A\triangle B$ and so there can be no elements in both $C$ and $A\cap B$. Put another way, $$(A\cap B)\cap C=A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset.$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement $A\cap B\cap C=\varnothing$ doesn't mean that the sets are disjoint. It means that $C$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint.

Indeed, recall that $A\triangle B$ is the same as $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$. So if $C\subseteq A\triangle B$ then $C\cap(A\cap B)=\varnothing$.

Comment: That was very helpful!  How does this look?
Let x be an arbitrary ∈ C.  Suppose C ⊆A.  Therefore, since A∩B=∅, x ∉ B.  That means x ∈ A\B ∪ C.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof of the equivalence, starting at the most complex side, expanding definitions and simplifying:
\begin{align}
&  C \subseteq A \cup B \;\land\; A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand definitions of $\;\subseteq,\cup,=,\cap\;$ and basic property of $\;\varnothing\;$"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: x \in C  \Rightarrow  x \in A \lor x \in B \rangle  \;\land\; \langle \forall x :: \lnot (x \in A \land x \in B \land x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify: combine both $\;\forall x\;$; rewrite $\;\Rightarrow\;$; DeMorgan"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: (x \not\in C \lor x \in A \lor x \in B)  \land  (x \not\in A \lor x \not\in B \lor x \not\in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify: extract common disjunct $\;x \not\in C\;$"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: x \not\in C  \lor  ((x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \not\in A \lor x \not\in B)) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rewrite as implication, twice -- we want to combine these conjuncts"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: x \not\in C  \lor  ((x \not\in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \land (x \in B \Rightarrow x \not\in A)) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify: mutual implication is equivalence"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: x \not\in C  \lor  (x \not\in A \equiv x \in B) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rewrite equivalence as inequivalence -- to introduce more symmetry"} \\
&  \langle \forall x :: x \in C  \Rightarrow  (x \in A \not\equiv x \in B) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce $\;\subseteq\;$ and $\;\triangle\;$ using their definitions"} \\
&  C \subseteq A \triangle B \\
\end{align}
Note that I used the following not-so-well-known definition of $\;\triangle\;$:
$$
x \in A \triangle B \;\equiv\; x \in A \;\not\equiv\; x \in B
$$
for any $\;A,B,x\;$.